# I am trying to create cookie while login with a user in Blazor web server app but I am bit lost

Tags: asp.net-core, cookies, blazor, blazor-server-side, httpcontext

I did check a lot of videos and tutorials on how to do in this days and now I am literally confused from how many options possible to achieve it, yet none really work well for me. I'm just trying to understand what is the best way for create a simple program structure where a user after login into admin page set creation of a cookie that could expire in 10 minute, but can get refreshed on every access to a page with authorize attribute. That's without the use of Entity Framework btw.
In this days I was experimenting it and I did menage to create cookie using controllers, is that the correct way to create cookie calling the controller function and let it create cookie with await `HttpContext.SignOutAsync` ? Otherwise I am open to any other suggestion but not point me again to documentations because I did try to understand from there but I get only more and more confused. btw I am working on Net 6.0 at the moment. Thank you for anyone that will point me out on some good resource to understand better this process.

As explained up I did check documentation and tried with the controller method but I want to know if I am doing it right or is a better way in Blazor to menage the user authorization and authentication ? Like `ProtectedSessionStorage`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot set cookies from a Blazor server-side session. You do not have access to the HttpContext and there isn't the traditional request/response cycle that you can use to return cookies in the response headers.

The approach I've has success with is to set up a login form in the usual Blazor way. If the login passes validation then I redirect to a traditional razor page (.cshtml file) that does have access to the HttpContext. After the cookie has been set I then redirect to the post-login page.

The same approach can be taken with logging out.

Below is a basic overview of the process.

```
<Blazor>
  @page "/login"
  - Render login form
  - Validate user input
  - Failure?
    - Display error message    
  - Success?  
    - Navigate to /dologin
</Blazor>

<Razor>
  @page "/dologin"
  - validate request
  - set auth cookie
  - navigate to /post-login
</Razor>

<Blazor>
  @page "/post-login"
  - validate cookie
  - continue session
  - ...
  - navigate to /logout
</Blazor>

<Razor>
  @page "/logout"
  - unset cookie
  - navigate to post-logout page
</Razor>

<Blazor>
  @page "/post-logout"
  - continue session
</Blazor>
```

Obviously this is a simplified representation, and doesn't go into any detail about post-login/logout redirect logic. Nor does it cover what abstraction you are using for auth management. In my project I use `SignInManager` from `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity`, but that is simply my choice of implementation and not related to my choice of workflow.

#### Edit

As described above, after I have validated the username and password, I navigate to the page that sets the auth cookie. Now because this is just another URL, we need to have a trusted way of identifying the authenticated user. We don't want to pass the username and the password in the URL for security reasons. To work around this I create a one-time token in my database after the credentials are validated and associate it with the user and use that to identify the user. I set the token to expire after a short time to improve security.

Relevant steps of the workflow:

```
<Blazor>
  @page "/login"
  - Valid credentials?
    - Create token for user in database
    - Navigate to /dologin?token=ABC123
</Blazor>

<Razor>
  @page "/dologin"
  - Get token from query string
  - Retrieve token from database
  - Token valid?
    - Delete token from database
    - Set auth cookie
</Razor>
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, I did tried a solution with a simple project where from a login page I do navigate to page called "/auth/login" using NavigationManager 
NavigateTo($"/auth/login?u={username}&p={psw}" and then in the controller I get the HttpContext.SignInAsync and create che cookie with the claims, I know it's ugly but it worked. So to be clear, I'm doing it in the totally wrong way ? Thank you for explain me, I am kinda new so I'm still looking for explanations

Comment: I wouldn't put sensitive information in the URL, but in principle that's similar to the workflow I described. I'll edit my answer to describe my password workaround.

Comment: Thank you for the edit, I am still learning but you gave me another thing to learn about. So basically is possible anyway to use httpcontext anyway but not on a Blazor page or component, if I understand well.

Comment: Correct. Blazor server side uses web sockets, which behave differently from your regular http request/response connections - one side effect being that you can't set cookies using web sockets (at least in a default Blazor app anyway).

Comment: It's again me, just to clarify another doubt I have regarding the cookie stuff, let's say that just for testing purpouse I want to clear the actual cookie made during the first login process of the user. At this stage my Blazor application not know I have no more cookie on the system and show that I am still validated in the application, until I do a refresh of all the application right ? For intercept this event how could I do a testing on the cookie existance ? Thank you

Comment: If my answer helped you, please upvote and mark as the solution. If my question didn't help, please let me know why. If you have a new question, please ask a new question. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your use of controllers with cookies is generally correct and straightforward.

As already mentioned, you really cannot use Blazor normal components for settings cookies, as you don't have access to `HttpContext`. To set a cookie, you need a HTTP call **from browser** to acquire and persist the cookie *on client side*. Usually common WebAPI service is a good choice here.

### What will NOT work for setting cookies:

- you cannot call the cookie setting logic directly from interactive blazor serverside component, as blazor components live on long-living signalR connection. Cookies don't travel inside http body or inside signalR pipe, but in HTTP headers.
- You can technically call the authentication service using `HTTPClient` on serverside blazor component, but this will not work as your authentication cookie would end up in HttpClient response object on server, and not in client browser.

#### What would work:

- use JSInterop or just plain client-side JS to pass credetials to authentication service using `fetch`, which will return a cookie for server. Every call to that domain. API and blazor HTTP calls alike will now include you r authentication state.
- You could verify credentials with blazor and use JSInterop etc to just write the cookie manually using JS, so separate service and HTTP call to server  would not be needed at all.

I would prefer the first option with service, because it is more universally usable, and could set cookies using `HttpOnly` flag, which is is a huge help to avoid your authenticated session from travelling to attackers hands in case of XSS vulnerabilities.

#### About `ProtectedSessionStorage`

This is nothing to do with cookies, but that could be a cookieless alternative that is relatively easy to implement. Just implement you own `AuthenticationStateProvider` instance to get/set your authentication state from/to `ProtectedSessionStorage`.

The important factor to consider is that `ProtectedSessionStorage` will require JSInterOP to communicate with storage on browser, and hence it will work only for Blazor interactive mode. That is, authentication state can only acquired once page is sent and SignalR connection is up. Should you want to upgrade to .net 8 and use static SSR render mode, prerendering and other newer tricks, this will get funky or just plain break.

It will also require more custom code if you also need to share the authentication state with non-blazor parts, i.e. some WebApi services. You could create JWT tokens or the like, but using plain old cookies do seem a good and simple choice that would work as well.